# Shortcut keys not working in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: asp.net-mvc, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2012

Having problem with the shortcuts for MVC specifically in VS2012.

> The key combination (CTRL+M, CTRL+G) is bound to command (Go To View)
>   which is not currently available.

But for example Refactor->Rename work.

- Disabling ReSharper doesn't help.
- It works in VS2010, but not in VS2012.

I have looked at the related question: [Shortcut keys not working (Visual Studio 2010 with ASP.NET MVC 3 RC1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4342501/shortcut-keys-not-working-visual-studio-2010-with-asp-net-mvc-3-rc1)

Had that problem previously in VS2010, and the accepted answer solved that problem.

Comment: I think the problem in essence is the same. On my machine the shortcuts only work on MVC 4 projects and not MVC 3.

Comment: I have to have both installed, so uninstalling MVC3 isn't an option.

Comment: Is your problem affecting MVC 3 & 4 projects? Or only MVC 3 projects in Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: Are you sure you're in the right window? (not solution explorer for example)

Comment: yes, I'm sure I'm in the correct window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem too. The problem was with the project file and this worked for me:

1. Create a new MVC project (you can use the Basic template)
2. Open the newly created project file and copy the <ProjectTypeGuids> element
3. Open the project file giving the problem and replace its <ProjectTypeGuids> element
4. Reload the project and it should work.

Comment: Works perfectly. Only one problem though: You can't open it in VS2010 any more.